# Перемещение по QML PolarChartView

Tags: qml, диаграммы

Всем привет, пишу приложение для отображения самолетов по аналогии с flight radar, пытаюсь сделать перемещение по графику (влево, вправо и тп), но у меня происходит только приближение или отдаление, пробовал использовать chart.scrollUp/Down/...
но это не работает должным образом, возможно я не правильно их использую.

```
PolarChartView {
        id: chartView
        title: "Two Series, Common Axes"
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisAngular
            min: 0
            max: 360
            tickCount: 9
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisRadial
            min: 0
            max: 250
        }


        SplineSeries {
            id: series1
            axisAngular: axisAngular
            axisRadial: axisRadial
            pointsVisible: true
        }

        ScatterSeries {
            id: series2
            axisRadial: axisRadial
            markerSize: 8
            color: "green"
            pointsVisible: true
        }
        ScatterSeries {
            id: series3
            axisRadial: axisRadial
            markerSize: 10
            color: "blue"
            pointsVisible: true
        }
        Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active

        MouseArea
        {
            id:mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true


            drag.target: parent
            drag.axis: Drag.XandYAxis

            onWheel:
            {
                if(wheel.angleDelta.y > 0)
                {
                    if(axisRadial.max > 20)
                    {
                        axisRadial.max = axisRadial.max * 0.5
                        axisAngular.tickCount = axisAngular.tickCount + 2
                        if(axisRadial.max >= 250)
                            axisAngular.tickCount = 9

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(axisRadial.max < 500)
                    {
                        axisRadial.max = axisRadial.max / 0.5
                        axisAngular.tickCount = axisAngular.tickCount - 2
                        if(axisRadial.max >= 250)
                            axisAngular.tickCount = 9
                    }
                }
            }

            onClicked:
            {
                if(mouseArea.hoverEnabled)
                {
                    //UP
                    if(((mouseX > 438) && (mouseX < 658)) && ((mouseY > 145)&&(mouseY<206)))
                        chartView.scrollUp(5)

                    //Down
                    if(((mouseX > 438) && (mouseX < 658)) && ((mouseY > 520)&&(mouseY<581)))
                        chartView.scrollDown(5)

                    //Left

                    //Right

                }
            }
        }
    }
Component.onCompleted: {
            series2.append(20, 140);
            series2.append(50, 40);
            series2.append(100, 128);
            series2.append(247, 50);
            series2.append(98, 140);
            series2.append(334, 80);
        }
```